# gdb load debug-info failed, get Dwarf Error when I debug webrtc peerconnection_client

Tags: gdb, webrtc, dwarf, peer-connection

Now, I build out peerconnection_client of google webrtc project.
But, when input command: `gdb out/Default/peerconnection_client`, I get error:

> Reading symbols from
>   /opt/dada/src/webrtc/native/src/out/Default/peerconnection_client...Dwarf
>   Error: compilation unit with DW_AT_GNU_dwo_name has children (offset
>   0x59d0) [in module
>   /opt/dada/src/webrtc/native/src/out/Default/peerconnection_client] (no
>   debugging symbols found)...done.

when I use command: `readelf --debug-dump=info out/Default/peerconnection_client | grep -C 5 0x59d0`

[image: ]]

Any suggestion,
Best regards!

Comment: What GDB version?

Comment: **gdb**: (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-94.el7

Comment: **gcc**: (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)

Comment: Have no useful idea, but assuming it could be a GDB issue, I would take 7.12 source, build it (it's really easy) and try with that version.

Comment: Aha @dbrank0 , your are greate !!!    Just build gdb-7.12, I can load debug-info successfully.